# Why is this initialized and configured Dispatcher Servlet not processing any request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm working on a library that needs to register its controllers beans on the Web Application Context of the application using that library. So that the application can access the library's controllers and configuration beans.

The application is already using a servlet initializer : (I can't modify the application source code)

```
@Order(1)
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    /** Constructor */
    public SpringServletInitializer() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringCoreConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringWebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "ADMIN_PROFILE");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

I tried creating a new `DispatcherServlet` either by extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` or by implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`. But in both ways the new DispatcherServlet, even though it is initialized and configured successfully, is never called. The application still uses its own dispatcher servlet and not both.

```
public class CustomConfJavaInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(CustomApiConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(
                "dispatcher2", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/custom");
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class CustomConfJavaInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "ADMIN_PROFILE");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

      @Override
      protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{CustomApiConfiguration.class};
      }


      @Override
      protected String getServletName() {
        return "dispatcher2";
      }


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/", "/custom", "/custom/*"};
    }   

}
```

I would have prefered to just modify the default dispatcher servlet and add my configuration but I'm not sure how I can do it ?

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet|DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/app-back/custom/ping]
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping|Matching patterns for request [/custom/ping] are [/**]
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping|URI Template variables for request [/custom/ping] are {}
```

But still, since we are allowed to have multiple Dispatcher Servlets why is the "dispatcher2" never called ?

I tried extending `ServletInitializer` so my class is called first and it seems to actually work. My `dispatcher2` is called for every single request but not their Dispatcher Servlet `dispatcher`. Does it mean that the first dispatcher created is the only dispatcher called ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second dispacher should Implement `WebApplicationInitializer` :

```
public class CustomConfJavaInitializer 
   implements WebApplicationInitializer {
```

Comment: I already tried that in my class `CustomApiInitializer`.
Or do you mean to both implement `WebApplicationInitializer` and extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`in my `CustomConfJavaInitializer` class ?

Comment: @redAce you should have different name and  both implement `WebApplicationInitializer`

Comment: I tried implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` in my `CustomConfJavaInitializer` class but same result. First dispatcher created is always the one called.

Comment: @redAce did you changed `getServletName` to return different value?

Comment: Yes I did, dispatcher and dispatcher2.

Comment: I updated my post in case you had any confusion of classes names.